# problem while comparing char with relational operators

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ValidString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        //String s = scan.nextLine();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println(isValidString(str));
        scan.close();
    }

    public static boolean isValidString(StringBuilder str) {
        for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++) {
        int s = (int)newStr.charAt(i);
            if(s>=97 && s<=122 || s>=65 && s<=90){
                
                continue;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I was expecting the output as true if string contains only Alphabets else false value.
Can anyone trace out what's the problem with this code.

Comment: condition `str.charAt(i)<='A' && str.charAt(i)>='Z' && str.charAt(i)<='a' && str.charAt(i)>='z')` is never satisfied.

Comment: To put it more simply - imagine you were dealing with integers. Your condition would be something like `if (x <= 5 && x >= 10 && x <= 25 && x >= 30)`. What value would you expect to satisfy all those parts? (I'd also suggest that if you call `str.charAt(i)` *once* and store the result in a local variable to use in your condition multiple times, your condition is likely to end up being more readable.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I was trying to relate charAt() values with the Ascii table reference

Comment: Yes, I realise that - but I suggest you look *really carefully* at what I've suggested (both parts). What value of `x` is both "less than or equal to 5" *and* "greater than or equal to 10"? Then apply that same thinking to character comparisons.

Comment: @SURAJMAHAKAL you're missing the point of the comments. Try a sample input string for which  `isValidString(StringBuilder str)` is supposed to return `true`.  Pretend you are the computer, and follow the logic of that method. Use pen and paper for your computer memory. Create truth tables with columns such as `c <='A'`, `c>='Z'`, and so on.

Comment: ... where `c`, in my previous comment, represents the current value pointed to by `str.charAt(i)`.

Comment: A version of this is common question on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, I'm not good at finding the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you will never have a character that is `<= A` and `>=Z` because the range `A-Z` is contiguous and ascending. The same is true for the range `a-z`. So instead of 
`str.charAt(i)<='A' && str.charAt(i)>='Z' && str.charAt(i)<='a' && str.charAt(i)>='z'` 
you need this - 
`!(str.charAt(i)>='A' && str.charAt(i)<='Z') && !(str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z')`